# How can I run nodejs in eclipse?(javascript runtime does not appear in eclipse preferences)

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse

Maybe similar questions found but those are very old and recommending outdated plugins.
-I'm using eclipse Ide for enterprise java developers 2021-06 and installed Nodejs 16.3 and Npm.
As [eclipse news](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2016/may/article3.php)
says, Eclipse Neon  and later will support jnodejs by default and you can configure runtime but I don't see any runtime in javaScript section in preferences and any option related to nodeJs and JavaScript in import sections.
I tried to install nodeClipse plugin but encountered errors.
When I import nodeJs project as general project, I get this error.
C:\Users\Hamidreza Abroshan\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.12.0.RELEASE.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.embedder.node\node-v14.15.4-win-x64\node.exe index.js
D:\dclm\dclm-customer-interaction-worker\dclm\node_modules\grpc\src\grpc_extension.js:55
throw error;
^

Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: node-v83-win32-x64-unknown
Found: [node-v93-win32-x64-unknown]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
Original error: Cannot find module 'D:\dclm\dclm-customer-interaction-worker\dclm\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node'
Require stack:

- D:\dclm\dclm-customer-interaction-worker\dclm\node_modules\grpc\src\grpc_extension.js

**Note: I can run this project from command line successfully with npm run start.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can this issue reproduced with the current version of [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) (update via _Help > Install New Software..._ working with the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/snapshots`](https://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/snapshots))? If yes, please provide an example with which it can be reproduced. Node.js is embedded in the Eclipse JEE IDE, so no need to install it on your system.

Comment: howlger, eclipse wild web developers is installed by default along eclipse for enterprise java developers. please review my answer and if you have any comments, please note here.

Answer (score 2):

I found this way, but if you found better way, please post your answer.
First, import the app as general project E.G, file>import>general>existing project in to workSpace.
Then, open project explorer view and find package.json.
Write click on that and choose run configuration.

choose launch npm and create new configuration.
Now, in npm command enter run start and in package.json file enter the file's address.
Hit run and your app will run successfully.
This config should be done for the first time and for later times, you can go to runAs and choose npm...
If you can not find package.json, open Cmd and navigate to project root folder and type npm run start and it will download some dependencies and create package.json also.

Comment: Great that you found an answer yourself. IMHO Eclipse Wild Web Developer should provide more documentation and some more dialogs for such things. Please consider to contribute to Wild Web Developer.